# wash_out | XML in payload has &lt; &gt; instead of < >

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, wash-out

[wash_out](https://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out/)(0.9.0) has been very helpful for me in implementing a SOAP service in my Rails(3.1) app. One little problem I am facing is that for XML payload in the SOAP body,  `< >` are getting replaced by 
`&lt;  &gt;`

Here's my code snippet

`render :soap => "<person><firstname>larry</firstname></person>"`

Output is

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Body>
    <tns:index_response>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;person&gt;&lt;firstname&gt;larry&lt;/firstname&gt;&lt;/person&gt;</value>
    </tns:index_response>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`

Is this a bug or can I fix this by some configuration or additional code. 
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (didn't test it):

```
render :soap => "<person><firstname>larry</firstname></person>".html_safe
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this. There was 1 thing I was doing wrong.

I am using [savon](http://savonrb.com/) client to call my SOAP service. I was doing
`client = Savon::Client.new(wsdl: "")`
`result = client.call(...)`
`puts result`

This was displaying `&lt;` and `&gt;`

The right way to access the response content in my case is
`result.body[:index_response][:value]`
`result.body` returns a hash

With Nokogiri I could do `doc = Nokogiri::XML(result.body.to_xml)`

This works well with XML in payload.